# Programatically creating products with custom attributes

Tags: product, magento2.3, catalog

I'm creating a product with a set of attributes using a cli script.

First of I'm setting the session for `\Magento\Framework\App\State` with `setAreaCode('adminhtml')` in the constructor. Then calling to a function which will create the product using the following:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository
}

public function saveProduct(array $data): void
{
    $product = $this->getProduct($data['sku']);

    $product->setVisibility(self::DEFAULT_VISIBILITY);
    $product->setStatus(Status::STATUS_DISABLED);

    $product->setName($data['name']);
    $product->setSku($data['sku']);
    $product->setPrice($data['price']);
    $product->setAttributeSetId($product->getDefaultAttributeSetId());

    $product->setCustomAttribute('hardiness', $data['hardiness']);
    $product->setCustomAttribute('name_latin', $data['name_latin']);
    $product->setCustomAttribute('store_aisle_table', 1);
    $product->setCustomAttribute('store_aisle', $data['store_aisle']);

    $this->productRepository->save($product);
    $this->productRepository->save($product);
}

private function getProduct(string $sku): ProductInterface
{
    $product = null;

    try {
        $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
    } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        $product = $this->productFactory->create();
    }

    return $product;
}
```

So first of all the weirdness with using `$this->productRepository->save()` twice. It appears to me that some data cannot be set before the product exists in the database. e.g. the 'price' field doesn't appear until I've used the `save()` function twice. However some of the attributes such as 'price' are required and as a result it won't save the first time if this value hasn't already been set.

The trouble is that the values set in the `setCustomAttribute()` function never appear in the admin.

From what I could discern from the database, once I do the second `save()` some other extra fields also appear in the database, specifically I was looking at the `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table, and the dummy values I had assigned to `store_ailse` had appeared in relation to the correct `entity_id`, however when I look at the product from the admin panel they don't show up though.

Through some digging it appears that there is a bug in Magento 2.3 with the `setCustomAttribute()` function, however if I save the fields using the form in `Catalog > Products` to create a new product these fields get correctly filled in, so how is this form achieving it then.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass **editMode** mode on `get(`) method.
See the function signature:

`Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::get($sku, $editMode = false, $storeId = null, $forceReload = false)`

```
$product = $this->productRepository->get($sku,true);
```

Comment: Would this not only work if the product already exists and you want to edit it? i.o.w. in the case of a new product, so when it calls the `productFactory->create()` method this wouldn't be the case no?